# device send what unique device certificate to APNS

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

i hava a question for APNs create Device Token.
 device token will change so it must have something to make that happened.

when device login APNS to ask device token  what kinds of values it send ?
for example :(phone number , time,Device Version)

can anyone helps?thank!

Comment: Your app will be informed about the new token, so what ever you want to send to your server with the token is op to you. (as long a it fits within the privacy state of Apple). The user phone number is not accessible in the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device sends its certificate to APNS.

> Service-to-Device Connection Trust
>
> APNs establishes the identity of a connecting device through TLS peer-to-peer authentication. (Note that the system takes care of this stage of connection trust; you do not need to implement anything yourself.) In the course of this procedure, a device initiates a TLS connection with APNs, which returns its server certificate. The device validates this certificate and then **sends its device certificate to APNs, which validates that certificate**.
>
> ...
>
> APNs generates a device token using information contained in the unique device certificate. The device token contains an identifier of the device. It then encrypts the device token with a token key and returns it to the device.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW3)

Comment: i'm not really understand certificate does it include some device message?

Comment: @facebook-100001564118706 It includes information about the device that allows APNS to verify the identity of that device.

Comment: i'm curious about what information includes.but still  thankful that your can  help me !